# Why does BASIC have a restricted identifier format?

Tags: language-design, basic

I've read that BASIC only allows identifiers to be composed of a capital letter, a number, another capital letter, then a $ symbol. Why is this the case? Is this related to how much memory BASIC can accommodate?

Comment: Which BASIC? I was using a BASIC in 1978 that allowed long identifiers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I really have no idea. This came from a class handout. But I made a mistake in the description, the handout says that identifiers are composed of a capital letter, a number, another capital letter, then a $ symbol, I've made the edits. Maybe you've encountered something of that sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very first versions of BASIC on the very early microcomputers, like Radio Shack's TRS-80 Model I had serious limitations on variable naming conventions, but from memory, the only reason you needed a capital letter was because that particular model only had upper case letters.  Lower case would not be available until the Model III was released, but I believe other popular computers at that time, like Atari and Apple, and maybe Commodore PET could do lower case, too.  There was a limitation in memory, so variables were limited, I believe, to two characters, the first of which had to be a letter, so AA or A1 for example, and the $ part designated what kind of variable, in this case a string variable.  A percent sign (%) would denote an integer, and I believe if it had floating point numbers, ! was for single-precision and # for double precision numbers.  Other types would be added in much later versions of BASIC as well as allowing much longer variable names.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Makes me appreciate how much progress we've made in the field of programming languages.

Comment: Maybe you could extend the answer by adding that longer names would have had run time implications too for memory constrained interpreted language implementation.

Answer (score -2):

Because only a fixed amount of memory was given for variables, so to save space Microsoft limited variable names to two characters (you can use more but they will be ignored by the parser).

BTW, the Sinclair ZX-81 had no such restriction - the memory was unmapped so variable names could be any length.

The Atari, Commodore (from Vic onwards) and Apple IIe (not II or II+) had lower case, but not at the same time.  BASIC is not case sensitive.

Variables were by default integers in most BASICs, the exception being PETBasic (Commodore) which always stored variables as floating point numbers and converted them to integers before calculation if they were designated as integers.

Comment: Microsoft did not invent BASIC.

Comment: @john The „fixed amount of memory“ is a bit misleading. Microsoft's earlier BASICs had a fixed amount of memory *per variable* including name and type and either the value directly (scalar numbers) or a pointer to the value (strings and arrays). The amount of memory for program and variables was managed dynamically.